# Open/execute batch file on double click

Tags: windows-7, command-line, file-association, window

I have created a batch file(.bat file). I am not sure, due to some reasons its not running when i double click on it.

I configured `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations`

.bat file as `windows command processor` and retried still file path is opening in does prompt. but file is not running. Please help me.

Comment: What happens when you do double click it? Does it do nothing? prompt you? open in notepad?

Comment: @miles hayler: if the file is on desktop, path of desktop is opening in command prompt. Then i can able to run it by typing file name. It is became 2 step process.

Comment: Pasting the content of bat, will make it easier to help.

Comment: @lamb: i dont have any problem while running content. Its a problem with default file association of windows.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled or disabled? If it's opening the command prompt then it know what it's supposed to do with it in terms of file association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all, I found a solution for my problem `http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html`. [click here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html)

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to actually write the answer so that it also works aftert the link to an external site has died.